# Nodejs - split string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following string:

```
'SCAR-20 | Sand Mesh (Battle-Scarred)'
```

I need to break this into 3 different sections, my output should be 3 variables - example:

```
var part1 = 'SCAR-20';
var part2 = 'Sand Mesh';
var part3 = 'Battle-Scared';
```

Though the string will change the structure of the string will always be the same:

```
'part1 | part2 (part3)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty bad at regex, but this works;

```
var str = 'SCAR-20 | Sand Mesh (Battle-Scarred)'
var regex = /(.+) \| (.+) \((.+)\)/
var match = str.match(regex);
var part1 = match[1];
var part2 = match[2];
var part3 = match[3];
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h40sd24z/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex to get it:

```
var re = /^(.*).?\|(.*)\((.*)\)/; 
var str = 'SCAR-20 | Sand Mesh (Battle-Scarred)';
var m;

m = str.match(re,'');
var firstPart = m[1];
var secondPart = m[2].trim();
var thirdPart = m[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively without regex:

```
var first = 'part1 | part2 (part3)'.split('|');
var second = first[1].split('(');
var part1 = first[0].trim();
var part2 = second[0].trim();
var part3 = second[1].substring(0, second[1].indexOf(')')).trim();
console.log(part1, part2, part3);
```